# Sending mails from an SMTP server

Tags: c#, java, email, smtp

I know that to send an e-mail from an SMTP server, one needs a server address, password and username/default credentials. But, does SMTP also have a password to access the server itself ? Is there a username as well ?

Comment: Why have you tagged both C# and Java? are you looking for implementation?

Comment: @I3arnon - No, I am not looking for code. Only the concept. Since C# and Java are popular and many programmers might have done smtp mails already, i tagged it with java and C#. It will help my post get the attention it needs. Who says - okay ! today i am going to try some smtp questions ?

Comment: Irrelevant tagging in attempts to get attention can't be commended.

Comment: @punund - okay, then let me add that a C# solution is preferred. I had no choice. Besides, even if i put a boounty of 250 on it later, it still might not get the attention it needs because people would still not be looking for smtp questions.

Comment: @blasto I gave a basic example. I think you need to clarify exactly what you are trying to accomplish though, your wording isn't clear enough. Are you simply trying to send an email from code?

Comment: @b1tsh1ft - yes, that is what i am trying to do.

Comment: @blasto ok take a look at my answer let me know if that is what you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is

- hostname: smtp.servername.com
- port: 25 or 465 (depending on if SSL)
- username: myuser
- password: mypassword

You do not need a password to the "server itself" or anything like that.

Depending on the server config, the email you send "from" may or may not need to be a valid email address on that server.

EDIT: basic C# implementation

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.To.Add("luckyperson@online.microsoft.com");
message.Subject = "This is the Subject line";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("yourmailuser@yourhost.com",25);
message.Body = "This is the message body";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");
// if you need user/pass login
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username","password");
smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: This is to send mail _to_ SMTP server, not to send it _from_ SMTP server.

Comment: @punund So you are suggesting that the code emulates an SMTP server talking to the destination SMTP server.. Sounds weird.

Comment: Thanks. But, actually, I have already implemented that code. But, it is useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

This is the inplementation that works for me:

```
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            message.To.Add("receiveremailaddress@xxx.com");
            message.Subject = "This is the Subject line";
            message.From = new MailAddress("youremailaddress@xxx.it", "Name to Display");
            message.Body = "This is the message body";
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("youremailaddress@xxx.it", "yourpassword");
            smtp.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

"But, does SMTP also have a password to access the server itself ? Is there a username as well ?"

No, the only password you may need is for a credentialed email account.